# cannot access '/dev/video*'

Tags: ros, linux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I would really appreciate your help.

I am having an issue with accessing to my web cam from my Lenovo Laptop (running Ubuntu 20.04).

```
yuxiang@yuxiang:/etc/modprobe.d$ ls /dev/video*
ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory


yuxiang@yuxiang:/etc/modprobe.d$ fswebcam -r 640x480 --no-banner image3.jpg
--- Opening /dev/video0...

yuxiang@yuxiang:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch my_camera elp.launch
uvc_find_device: No such device (-4)
[ERROR] [1645657833.102061279, 1575.456000000]: Unable to open camera.
^C[libuvc_camera-2] killing on exit
[nodelet_manager-1] killing on exit
[ INFO] [1645657841.057052676, 1583.374000000]: Unloading nodelet /libuvc_camera from manager /nodelet_manager
shutting down processing monitor...



yuxiang@yuxiang:~/catkin_ws$ hwinfo --usb
02: USB 00.0: 0000 Unclassified device                          
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: Zj8l.Y_aYp4agq10
  Parent ID: pBe4.xYNhIwdOaa6
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 2-4:1.0
  Hardware Class: unknown
  Model: "Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Depth Camera 435"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x8086 "Intel Corp."
  Device: usb 0x0b07 "Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Depth Camera 435"
  Revision: "50.b1"
  Serial ID: "933623025074"
  Module Alias: "usb:v8086p0B07d50B1dcEFdsc02dp01ic0Eisc01ip00in00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: uvcvideo is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe uvcvideo"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #14 (Hub)

03: USB 00.0: 0000 Unclassified device
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: POWV.ZGXmp31lfyE
  Parent ID: k4bc.2DFUsyrieMD
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 1-9:1.0
  Hardware Class: unknown
  Model: "Synaptics Unclassified device"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x06cb "Synaptics, Inc."
  Device: usb 0x00bd 
  Serial ID: "46be90c14e26"
  Speed: 12 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v06CBp00BDd0000dcFFdsc10dpFFicFFisc00ip00in00"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #10 (Hub)

04: USB 00.1: 0000 Unclassified device
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: QR8P.z1tM_FB91k0
  Parent ID: k4bc.2DFUsyrieMD
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.1
  SysFS BusID: 1-8:1.1
  Hardware Class: unknown
  Model: "Acer Integrated Camera"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x5986 "Acer, Inc"
  Device: usb 0x115f "Integrated Camera"
  Revision: "56.14"
  Serial ID: ""
  Speed: 480 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v5986p115Fd5614dcEFdsc02dp01ic0Eisc02ip00in01"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #10 (Hub)


 yuxiang@yuxiang:~$ /usr/sbin/lsmod | sort

ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
acpi_pad              184320  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
aesni_intel           372736  4
arp_tables             24576  0
aufs                  262144  0
autofs4                45056  2
binfmt_misc            24576  1
bluetooth             552960  11 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
bnep                   24576  2
bpfilter               32768  0
bridge                176128  1 br_netfilter
br_netfilter           28672  0
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                24576  1 btusb
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
btusb                  57344  0
ccm                    20480  6
cfg80211              708608  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
coretemp               20480  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
drm                   491520  16 drm_kms_helper,i915
drm_kms_helper        184320  1 i915
e1000e                258048  0
ecc                    28672  1 ecdh_generic
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
hid                   131072  3 i2c_hid,hid_multitouch,hid_generic
hid_generic            16384  0
hid_multitouch         28672  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
i2c_hid                28672  0
i2c_i801               32768  0
i915                 1994752  39
idma64                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
int3400_thermal        20480  0
int3403_thermal        20480  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  2 int3403_thermal,processor_thermal_device
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_hid              20480  0
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
intel_lpss_pci         20480  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
intel_rapl_common      24576  2 intel_rapl_msr,processor_thermal_device
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
intel_soc_dts_iosf     20480  1 processor_thermal_device
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    20480  0
ip6table_filter        16384  0
ip6_tables             32768  1 ip6table_filter
iptable_filter         16384  1
iptable_nat            16384  1
ip_tables              32768  2 iptable_filter,iptable_nat
iwlmvm                380928  0
iwlwifi               331776  1 iwlmvm
joydev                 24576  0
kvm                   663552  0
ledtrig_audio          16384  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof,thinkpad_acpi
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
libcrc32c              16384  2 nf_conntrack,nf_nat
llc                    16384  2 bridge,stp
lp                     20480  0
mac80211              847872  1 iwlmvm
mac_hid                16384  0
mc                     53248  0
mei                   106496  3 mei_hdcp,mei_me
mei_hdcp               24576  0
mei_me                 40960  1
Module                  Size  Used by
msr                    16384  0
nf_conntrack          139264  4 xt_conntrack,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_netlink,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_conntrack_netlink    45056  0
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  1 nf_conntrack
nf_nat                 45056  2 iptable_nat,xt_MASQUERADE
nfnetlink              16384  3 nf_conntrack_netlink
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
nvme                   49152  2
nvme_core             102400  4 nvme
nvram                  16384  1 thinkpad_acpi
overlay               118784  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
parport_pc             40960  0
pinctrl_cannonlake     36864  1
pinctrl_intel          28672  1 pinctrl_cannonlake
ppdev                  24576  0
processor_thermal_device    24576  0
psmouse               155648  0
rapl                   20480  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
serio_raw              20480  0
snd                    90112  26 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,thinkpad_acpi,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp,snd_rawmidi
snd_compress           24576  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_codec         135168  6 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   131072  1
snd_hda_core           90112  11 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_hda_ext_core       32768  4 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hda_intel          53248  0
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_pcm               106496  10 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_soc_acpi_intel_match
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    32768  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_core          249856  6 snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_dmic,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_soc_dmic           16384  1
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_hdac_hdmi      36864  1 snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp    24576  6
snd_sof               106496  4 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_sof_intel_ipc
snd_sof_intel_byt      20480  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_hda_common    73728  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_intel_ipc      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof_pci            20480  2
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
sparse_keymap          16384  1 intel_hid
stp                    16384  1 bridge
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
thinkpad_acpi         110592  0
thunderbolt           167936  0
typec                  45056  1 typec_ucsi
typec_ucsi             40960  1 ucsi_acpi
ucsi_acpi              16384  0
video                  49152  2 thinkpad_acpi,i915
virt_dma               20480  1 idma64
wmi                    32768  2 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,wmi_bmof
wmi_bmof               16384  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
xfrm_algo              16384  1 xfrm_user
xfrm_user              36864  2
x_tables               40960  8 ip6table_filter,xt_conntrack,iptable_filter,xt_addrtype,ip6_tables,ip_tables,xt_MASQUERADE,arp_tables
xt_addrtype            16384  2
xt_conntrack           16384  2
xt_MASQUERADE          20480  2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396639/cannot-access-%27/dev/video*%27/) by [noname](https://answers.ros.org/users/98100/noname/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2022-02-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bribri123](https://answers.ros.org/users/78090/bribri123/) on 2022-02-24**:
maybe this tutorial can help http://roboticsweekends.blogspot.com/2017/12/how-to-use-usb-camera-with-ros-on.html

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-02-26**:
You do not seem to have loaded the video4linux2 drivers or the uvcvideo drivers into the linux kernel. Please edit your description to include the output of this terminal command:

/usr/sbin/lsmod | sort

**Comment by [noname](https://answers.ros.org/users/98100/noname/) on 2022-02-26**:
Thanks for the help folks. I have added the output after /usr/sbin/lsmod | sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have not loaded the video4linux2 drivers or the uvcvideo drivers into the linux kernel. There are many resources on the web to help you configure a usb webcam on linux. I suggest you get it working with an application like `cheese` before you try to use the camera in ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1